# POST between Python and PHP not working?

Tags: php, python, post

I`m trying to communicate between my website and a client side script. The Python client sends a POST to a PHP file, which then prints it to show me that the POST is working, so I can move on to the next step of my development. However, for some reason, I can only post to it with an HTML5 form, and not Python 3.5.2 requests module.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php

$data = ((!empty($_POST['data'])) ? $_POST['data'] : 'N/A');
echo $data;

?>
```

The Python:

```
    >>> import requests
    >>> url = "www.example.com/coords.php"
    >>> data = "This is a string"
    >>> r = requests.post(url, data)
    >>> r.content
    b'N/A'
```

The HTML5 that works:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="www.example.com/coords.php">
            <input type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data variable is not correct. Try following:

```
    >>> import requests
>>> url = "www.example.com/coords.php"
>>> data = {'data':'This is a string'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, data)
>>> r.content
b'N/A'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [requests manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) you will see that the `data` you send should be a dictionary:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "www.example.com/coords.php"
>>> data = "This is a string"
>>> r = requests.post(url, {'data': data})
```

The `key`s that you send (in the dictionary) are the same `key`s you should use inside your PHP code.

If you send:

```
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

You should use `$_POST['key1']` and `$_POST['key2']` in PHP (and their values are `val1` & `val2` accordingly.

Comment: I attempted to use a dictionary before: '''{"Success": "True"}''', however I`ll try this one.